# MetaMask - failed transaction, maximum gas rate suggested is to low

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, gas-limit, out-of-gas

I recently bought a code for a coin flip game and I have been modifying it while I learn to program. I have reached the point of launching the website but when I play and approve the transaction I receive the following message

[image]

After hours of research I realized that the problem is in the suggested gas rate that the contract sends to metamask.apparently it's too low

the suggested rate that is sent to metamask

[image]

maximum base rate and priority rate

[image]

When I change the gas option to low or market, the problem is solved and the transaction is carried out without problems.

you can take a look https://www.bsccoinflip.xyz/

Here I leave the code. Please if someone could help me modify the contract so that the suggested rate is correct and people do not have to modify the gas rate every time they try to play. Thank you.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// import "hardhat/console.sol";

/**
 * @dev Wrappers over Solidity's arithmetic operations with added overflow
 * checks.
 *
 * Arithmetic operations in Solidity wrap on overflow. This can easily result
 * in bugs, because programmers usually assume that an overflow raises an
 * error, which is the standard behavior in high level programming languages.
 * `SafeMath` restores this intuition by reverting the transaction when an
 * operation overflows.
 *
 * Using this library instead of the unchecked operations eliminates an entire
 * class of bugs, so it's recommended to use it always.
 */
library SafeMath {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the addition of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `+` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Addition cannot overflow.
     */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow (when the result is negative).
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
     */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the multiplication of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `*` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Multiplication cannot overflow.
     */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers. Reverts on
     * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
     * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
     * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
        require(b > 0, "SafeMath: division by zero");
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * Reverts when dividing by zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
        return a % b;
    }
}

/* --------- Access Control --------- */
contract Context {
    // Empty internal constructor, to prevent people from mistakenly deploying
    // an instance of this contract, which should be used via inheritance.
    function _msgSender() internal view returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}

contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(
        address indexed previousOwner,
        address indexed newOwner
    );

    constructor() {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal {
        require(
            newOwner != address(0),
            "Ownable: new owner is the zero address"
        );
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract Coinflip is Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    struct Bet {
        address playerAddress;
        uint256 betValue;
        uint256 headsTails;
    }

    mapping(address => uint256) public playerWinnings;
    mapping(address => Bet) public waiting;

    event logNewProvableQuery(string description);
    event userWithdrawal(address indexed caller, uint256 amount);
    event filpFinshed(uint result);

    uint256 lastHash;
    uint256 FACTOR =
        57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;

    uint public contractBalance;

    bool public freeCallback = true;

    constructor() {}

    function getResult() private returns (uint) {
        uint256 blockValue = uint256(blockhash(block.number.sub(1)));

        if (lastHash == blockValue) {
            revert();
        }

        lastHash = blockValue;
        uint256 coinFlip = blockValue % 2;
        uint side = coinFlip == 1 ? 1 : 0;
        return side;
    }

    /**
     *@notice This function simulates a coin flip which makes a call to the Provable oracle for
     *        a random number.
     *@dev The function first checks if this is the very first call to the Provable oracle in order
     *     for the user to not pay for the first free call. This also adds user values to two different
     *     mappings: 'waiting' and 'afterWaiting.' Both mappings are necessary in order to bridge the
     *     user's address (which we has access to here with msg.sender) and the user's queryId sent from
     *     Provable after the function call.
     *
     *@param oneZero - The numerical value of heads(0) or tails(1)
     */

    function flip(uint256 oneZero) public payable {
        require(contractBalance > msg.value, "We don't have enough funds");

        address _player = msg.sender;
        Bet memory postBet;
        postBet.playerAddress = msg.sender;
        postBet.betValue = msg.value;
        postBet.headsTails = oneZero;

        uint flipResult = getResult();

        if (flipResult == postBet.headsTails) {
            //winner
            emit filpFinshed(1);
            uint winAmount = SafeMath.sub(SafeMath.mul(postBet.betValue, 2), 0);
            contractBalance = SafeMath.sub(contractBalance, postBet.betValue);
            playerWinnings[_player] = SafeMath.add(
                playerWinnings[_player],
                winAmount
            );
        } else {
            //loser
            emit filpFinshed(0);
            contractBalance = SafeMath.add(
                contractBalance,
                // SafeMath.sub(postBet.betValue, postBet.setRandomPrice)
                SafeMath.sub(postBet.betValue, 0)
            );
        }
    }

    function withdrawUserWinnings() public {
        require(playerWinnings[msg.sender] > 0, "No funds to withdraw");
        uint toTransfer = playerWinnings[msg.sender];
        playerWinnings[msg.sender] = 0;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(toTransfer);
        emit userWithdrawal(msg.sender, toTransfer);
    }

    function getWinningsBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return playerWinnings[msg.sender];
    }

    /**
     *@notice The following functions are reserved for the owner of the contract.
     */

    function fundContract() public payable onlyOwner {
        contractBalance = SafeMath.add(contractBalance, msg.value);
    }

    function fundWinnings() public payable onlyOwner {
        playerWinnings[msg.sender] = SafeMath.add(
            playerWinnings[msg.sender],
            msg.value
        );
    }

    function withdrawAll() public onlyOwner {
        uint toTransfer = contractBalance;
        contractBalance = 0;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(toTransfer);
    }

    function claimETH(uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        (bool sent, ) = owner().call{value: amount}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The gas value is set in the UI code, not inside the contract. Usually, you would call estimateGas first and then add ~20% on top of that to ensure there is enough gas allocated for the transaction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. How would that function be written, in the UI code. to be able to modify it.